Amulet Map Editor (WX python program) can't render world in 3D mode
I am running Amulet Map Editor on my phone with these specs:
neofetch output
using Proot Arch Linux container in Termux on ARM64 CPU. VNC for output graphics.
My problem is that the proot Linux container cannot use the GPU of the phone, but only software rendering. This causes an error in the Amulet Map Editor so it can't render worlds:
screenshot

MESA: error: ZINK: vkCreateInstance failed (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)

libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen

(Do not pay attention to the error related to OpenGL_accelerate, it is not really needed)
but at the same time, some other 3D programs can work (yes, at 10 FPS, but they work) using software rendering, but Amulet cannot.
So I want to ask if there is a way to force it to use software rendering and work correctly?

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but here is the output of glxinfo:
glxinfo_output
Btw mesa-utils already installed. LLVM is 18.1.8
